# Обработка нажатия клавиш

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте! Помогите с написанием программы на Delphi об обработке нажатых клавиш. Суть в чем:
у нас есть `Radigroup` с двумя `Radio`: `onKeyPress` и `onKeyUp`. При выборе радиокнопки `onKeyPress` отображаются в memo–поле сведения о нажатой клавише в следующем формате:

```
KeyPress: <символ>(<код_символа>)
```

При выборе радиокнопки `onKeyUp` отображаются в memo–поле сведения о нажатой комбинации клавиш в следующем формате:

```
KeyUp: <нажатая комбинация клавиш>(<код клавиши>)
```

Исключить вывод отдельных строк об управляющих клавишах, нажимаемых при вводе комбинаций (значение `key` не должно равняться 16-`Shift`, 17-`Ctrl`, 18-`Alt`).

Не совсем понимаю, как связать событие нажатия `RadioGroup` с нажатием клавиши на клавиатуре.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простой способ: создайте ваши обработчики `onKeyPress` и `onKeyUp`, которые будут выводить текст в `Memo`, но не привязывайте их к компоненту.

В обработчике `RadioGroupOnChange()` в зависимости от выбора привязывайте один обработчик и отцепляйте другой.

Comment: а скажите, где найти эти коды символов? или их самому прописывать надо?

Comment: Прописывать не надо. У вас в обработчик события приходит символ `Key: Char`. Его просто нужно представить в  виде числа. Например, в шестнадцатиричной системе:

KeyCodeStr := Format('$%x', [Key]);